# SQL use rows as columns

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

How can I convert the following:

```
+------+---------+------+
| Date | Product | Sold |
+------+---------+------+
| 1/1  | P1      |  100 |
| 1/1  | P2      |  250 |
| 1/1  | P3      |   50 |
| 2/1  | P1      |  170 |
| 2/1  | P2      |    0 |
| 2/1  | P3      |   70 |
+------+---------+------+
```

Into a table like this:

```
+------+-----+-----+----+
| Date | P1  | P2  | P3 |
+------+-----+-----+----+
| 1/1  | 100 | 250 | 50 |
| 2/1  | 170 |   0 | 70 |
+------+-----+-----+----+
```

Using SQL?
I know the number of products (exactly 3).

Comment: Please look up pivots. Which database are you using?

Comment: PIVOT.  which database are you using?

Comment: @AmitBhargava I am using MySQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many DBMSes offer specific support for "pivots" or "crosstab reports", but if your DBMS does not, or if you prefer a solution that will work on a variety of DBMSes, you can write:

```
SELECT Date,
       MIN(CASE WHEN Product = 'P1' THEN Sold END) AS "P1",
       MIN(CASE WHEN Product = 'P2' THEN Sold END) AS "P2",
       MIN(CASE WHEN Product = 'P3' THEN Sold END) AS "P3"
  FROM ___insert_table_name_here___
 GROUP
    BY Date
;
```

**Edited to add:** You've now mentioned that you're using MySQL, which does *not* have special pivot or crosstab support, so the above the query is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If it is SQL Server 2005+:

```
SELECT
    Date 
    , [P1]
    , [P2]
    , [P3]
FROM
(
    SELECT
        Date
        , Product
        , Sold
    FROM
        ProductSold
) AS t1
PIVOT
(
    MIN(Sold)
    FOR Product IN ([P1], [P2], [P3])
) AS pvt
ORDER BY
    Date ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL if you have an unknown number of columns to rotate, then you can use [prepared statements](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html) and your code will look like this (See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11395/3)):

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`Date` datetime, `Product` varchar(7), `Sold` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`Date`, `Product`, `Sold`)
VALUES
    ('2001-01-01 00:00:00', 'P1', 100),
    ('2001-01-01 00:00:00', 'P2', 250),
    ('2001-01-01 00:00:00', 'P3', 50),
    ('2001-02-01 00:00:00', 'P1', 170),
    ('2001-02-01 00:00:00', 'P2', 0),
    ('2001-02-01 00:00:00', 'P3', 70)
;

SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(case when Product = ''',
      Product,
      '''  then sold else 0 end) AS ',
      Product
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM Table1;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Date, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM table1 
                  GROUP BY date');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```